# Writing results of a db search to a dynamic (possibly angular) page via extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

To begin, I would like to note that I am a complete extension noob, so please forgive me if this is a silly question. I have been working on this for a couple days and have found nothing on the web that helps with this particular problem.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Say that a user is browsing a site that displays part numbers and info. Each time the user clicks on something from the site, the site loads new information and the URL changes. The extension then grabs the UID (unique identifier) from the URL and searches a database for that UID. If the UID is found in the database, a message is returned to the extension. From here, I would like to write a div to the page saying "This part is already found in the database".

The problem here appears to be that the page changes, but it's not a new page... it's just new information. **I can get the extension to write to the page on initial load**, but when the page changes, nothing is written.

Here is the relevant code that I am using:

**Manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "An extension to write to a page",
  "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "16": "icon16.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon16.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts":["./js/jquery.min.js","./js/extension-check.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["./js/jquery.min.js","./js/extension-content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www.example.com/*"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

The popup.html does nothing but give some buttons that the user can click and go to some sites. It has no relevant code.

**extension-check.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        if (tabs === undefined || tabs[0] === undefined) return;

        var url = tabs[0].url;

        if (url.indexOf("example.com/specific-directory") > 0) {
            var part_url = // get part of the url
            var search_url = 'myexample.com/searching?' + part_url;

                $.ajax({
                    url: search_url,
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: async function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        if (Object.keys(data).length != 0 && data.constructor != Object) {
                            // Because this script is running in the 
                            // background, I need to send the command to 
                            // something that has permissions to write to the page
                            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
                                file: './js/extension-content.js'
                            }, function() {
                                 chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {parameter: data});
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**extension-content.js**

```
(function() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
        var receivedParameter = message.parameter;

        alert ("In this - " + receivedParameter);
        $(".core").prepend("<div>This is a test - " + receivedParameter + "</div>");
    });

})();
```

**NOTE**: If I change this page to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".core").prepend("<div>This is a test</div>");
});
```

The div IS written to the page. But, this is written to the page once and never changes or goes away. This would display incorrect information.

The ajax is working perfectly... The alert (which is only there for a test) does display and displays with the passed parameter. However, NOTHING is written to the page.

Can someone please help me? In addition, if I have something wrong in the manifest (such as permissions), I would be ecstatic for some feedback. Again, noob at this, so I may have added that I don't need, or don't have things that I do need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @wOxxOm I believe that's what the first line in the extension-check.js does. The code executes when the page is changed - I am getting the alert from extension-content.js every page change. However, I am not able to append to $(".core"). I have tried to find $(".core").length, and when the page is initially loaded, I get 1. But after the page is changed, I get 0. It's like the page disappears? Maybe I need to refocus on the document at each page change? But how do I do that?

Comment: Ah, indeed you already detect the URL change. Well, I guess you need to wait for the `.core` element to appear - the page arguably needs some time to process the data which incidentally occurs after your content script receives the message. You can periodically retry via setTimeout/setInterval ur use MutationObserver.

Comment: @wOxxOm Well, I tried that too. But even after a 5 - 10 second delay, and the page fully loaded, I can't seem to find `.core`. If I use the console, I can find it, but using the extension I cannot. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you were using for/while loops instead of setTimeout/setInterval, which is wrong. Or maybe it's inside an iframe in which case you need `"all_frames": true` in manifest.json's declaration of the content script.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was using a while loop, looking for `.core`. I just tried to add a timeout and it worked. Why does the while loop not work? If I do a while loop with a pause for 1 second, then look for that class again, it should work, right? But adding just the timeout did work. Please submit an answer for adding a timeout and I will accept it as the correct one.

Comment: Page environment is single-threaded so while your JS function runs nothing else can run there.